# Why 2 return statements are mandatory in equals method

Tags: java, return, equals

```
public class MyStuff {
    String name;

    MyStuff(String n) {
        name = n;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyStuff m1 = new MyStuff("guitar");
        MyStuff m2 = new MyStuff("tv"); 

        System.out.println(m2.equals(m1));
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        MyStuff m = (MyStuff) o;

        if (m.name != null)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

When i remove one of the return statements, compiler gives an error: This method must return a result of type boolean

Comment: fixing your indentation will help. The return true is a CONDITIONAL return, defined by the `if(m.name != null)` statement above it.

Comment: if you use java, use `{}` for if-clause!

Comment: you do not need the curly braces for if. however, if you do not use them, only the next line is considered IN the if statement.

Comment: if you use Eclipse try (Ctrl + Shift + F) to format your code then you will see why :D

Comment: Omission of {} can cause many bugs later. I've run into it quite a few times editing someone else's code. ALWAYS use the brackets.

Comment: I think it's a good question. He is a newbie, and now he's probably a better newbie.

Comment: The lack of understanding was literally from a lack of adherence to a reasonable coding style, and not using even the auto-formatter to properly indent things. This is kinda the reason why people think that for some people, it's better to make them learn programming in Python first. I don't really like Python because it's a debug hell, but at least it forces you to indent properly - otherwise nothing will work.

Comment: Thinking about what the code actually does would help as well. I would rather recommend replacing the code with `return m.name!=null;` which does the same rather than fixing the indentation or putting curly braces in. Still, it’s a nonsensical `equals` implementation. What you really want (most probably) is something like `return m.name.equals(this.name);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return true` is only executed if the `if` condition is true. For all other cases you need the `return false`

Answer (score 4):

That's quite obviously because your code is actually

```
....
    MyStuff m = (MyStuff) o;
    if(m.name != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please use brackets, and set up the Eclipse Formatter in Project -> Properties -> Java Code Style -> Formatter -> Configure Workspace Settings -> New -> make a profile that's actually good -> apply -> press Ctrl+Shift+F in code.

In fact, I personally recommend the following Formatter settings for Eclipse, it's the one I use: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4363931/BestEclipseFormatterSettings.xml

Answer (score 1):

If your case is really this simple, it would be much simpler to just return the result of your comparison:

```
return m.name != null;
```

There really is no value in doing a boolean comparison then separately using an if block to return the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you use only one return statement then equals() will return a result only when m.name!=null otherwise the method does not have any other return statement. So the compilar is giving error.